# Delete keys from dictionary based on condition in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries, in very documents I want to keep only words which are in group of 3( for ex 'done auto manufacturing')
and after filtering I wan to keep top 2 grams which based on values and if values are same then top two keys in the dictonary.

```
b=[{'america': 0.10640008943905088,
  'delete option snapshot': 0.18889748775492732,
  'done': 0.10918437741476256,
  'done auto manufacturing': 0.18889748775492732,
  'done auto delete': 0.18889748775492732,
  'overwhelmed': 0.1714953267142263,
  'overwhelmed sub': 0.18889748775492732,
  'overwhelmed sub value': 0.18889748775492732},
 {'delete': 0.17737631178689198,
  'delete invalid': 0.2918855502796403,
  'delete invalid data': 0.2918855502796403,
  'invalid': 0.19409701271823834,
  'invalid data': 0.2918855502796403,
  'invalid data sir': 0.2918855502796403,
  'nas': 0.14949544719217545,
  'nas server': 0.1632884084021329,
  'nas server replic': 0.2799865687396422}]
```

output:

```
    b=[{'delete option snapshot': 0.18889748775492732,
  'done auto manufacturing': 0.18889748775492732,
  'done auto delete': 0.18889748775492732,
  'overwhelmed sub value': 0.18889748775492732},
 {'delete invalid data': 0.2918855502796403,
  'invalid data sir': 0.2918855502796403}]
```

My solution: This doesn't seem right.

```
for i in range(1, len(b)+1):
    for k,v in i.items():
        if len(re.findall(r'\w+',k[i])<3:
               del  b[k]
```

Comment: what have you tried ?

Comment: `i.items` should be `b[i].items`. But it would be easier if you just used `for d in b:`.

Comment: `del b[k]` should be `del b[i][k]`

Comment: Why `range(1, len(b)+1)` instead of `range(0, len(b))`? You're skipping the first dictionary, and will try to access outside the list.

Comment: @barmar, i'm novice in python. I will take care of it from next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always good to use comprehensions. Because normally you shouldn't delete elements from lists or dicts while you iterate over it - this it very bad style and can cause errors. So it is better to create new dicts and lists, and replace the old list by the new one For updating the dict i would use:

```
{k:v for k,v in d.items if len(v.split(" "))>2}
```

In this case d is the dict. Now you can simply update/recreate the list with a list comprehension:

```
result = [{k:v for k,v in d.items() if len(k.split(" "))>2} for d in b]
```

Comment: getting error:`File "<ipython-input-126-796ae52c05e1>", line 2
    result = [{k:v for k,v in d.items() if len(re.findall(r'\w+',v)<3} for d in f]
                                                                     
SyntaxError: invalid syntax  at <3`

Comment: It seems like the find all from the orginal code is wrong i will edit it ... there is a missing bracket... Good catch thanks...

Comment: sorry! error is this `---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-130-1b14c2c2ce9c> in <module>()
      1 #import re
----> 2 result = [{k:v for k,v in d.items() if len(re.findall(r'\w+',v)<3)} for d in f]

<ipython-input-130-1b14c2c2ce9c> in <listcomp>(.0)
      1 #import re
----> 2 result = [{k:v for k,v in d.items() if len(re.findall(r'\w+',v)<3)} for d in f]

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'`

Comment: Do you have an error message the code above works for me in python if i create your example variables...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173909/discussion-between-user15051990-and-pils19).

Answer (score 0):

`i` is a number, so `i.items()` makes no sense. Since `i` is an index into the list, it should be `b[i].items()`.

But your range is wrong. List indexes start at `0`, not `1`, so it should be `range(0, len(b))`. But Python provides a simpler way to iterate over all the elements of a list:

```
for d in b:
```

So to filter out all the items that don't have 3 words in the key, it should be:

```
for d in b:
    for k in d:
        if len(re.findall(r'\w+',k)<3:
            del d[k]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
out = []
for item in b:
    d = dict()
    for key in item.keys():
        if len(key.split())>2:
            d[key] = item[key]
    out.append(d)
```

Comment: Try to explain the differences you made and why what the asker tried didn't work. Simply pasting code is not a helpful answer